# If else different onclick functions react?

Tags: reactjs

i have next code

```
<div className={"aside-minus "  + (item.quantity > 1 ? '' : 'remove')} 
  onClick={() => this.props.subQuantity(item.product._id)}>
</div>
```

The condition if item.quantity > 1 I 'not add class'
But i have function subQuantity.
The question
If item.quantity > 1 onClick function = subQuantity , else onClick function = remove
How make?
Thaks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can conditionally invoke any function you want in a callback function, it is just a function after all.

```
<div
  className={"aside-minus "  + (item.quantity > 1 ? '' : 'remove')} 
  onClick={() => {
    if (item.quantity > 1) {
      this.props.subQuantity(item.product._id);
    } else {
      // call remove function
    }
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

With a turnary

```
<div className={"aside-minus "  + (item.quantity > 1 ? '' : 'remove')} 
  onClick={item.quantity > 1 ? () => this.props.subQuantity(item.product._id) : () => this.remove()}>
</div>
```